# Drop down forms that when submitted load url

Tags: javascript, forms, url

I am trying to make a basic drop down forum which when options are selected they will load a URL on a submit button click.

I would like something like this

Drop down one

Make of bike:
KTM
BMW
Ect

Model of bike:
(if ktm was picked above would show)
990
EXC
Ect

(if BMW picked above would show)
GS
Adventure
Ect

So if make of bike was ktm and model was 990 on click of submit button would load
Www.website.com/ktm/990

this is the code i have i have got the picking part sorted so if you pick KTM it shows you models of KTM and the same with BMW the only problem is i cant get the url to work at all and have no real idea how to do it.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
 function setOptions(chosen) {
var selbox = document.myform.model;

selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');

}
if (chosen == "BMW") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('R1200-GS-Adventure','R1200-GS-Adventure');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('R1200-GS','R1200-GS');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('R1200-RT','R1200-RT');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('1150-GS-Adventure','1150-GS-Adventure');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('1150-GS','1150-GS');
}
if (chosen == "KTM") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('990','990');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('640','640');
}
if (chosen == "Yamaha") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Tenére 660XT','Tenére 660XT');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Super Tenére 1200XT','Super Tenére 1200XT');
}
}
// -->
</script>
```

and the form code

```
  <form name="myform"><div align="center">
<select name="bike" size="1"
onchange="setOptions(document.myform.bike.options[document.myform.bike.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
<option value="KTM">KTM</option>
<option value="Yamaha">Yamaha</option>
</select><br> <br>
<select name="model" size="1">
<option value=" " selected="selected">Please select one of the options above first</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="go" value="Search"
onclick="alert(document.myform.model.options[document.myform.model.selectedIndex].value);">
</div></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function to your script

Javascript:

```
function loadURL(){


    var bike = document.myform.bike.options[document.myform.bike.selectedIndex].value;
    var model = document.myform.model.options[document.myform.model.selectedIndex].value;


    if(bike != ' ' && model != ' '){

        var url = 'http://YOURWEBSITE.com/' + bike + '/' + model;
        window.location = url;

    }//if




}
```

And make this your submit button

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="go" value="Search" onclick="loadURL();">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the URL using simple concatenation of the selected options, and redirect to the chosen page by setting `location = "<new URL>"` in your button click handler:

```
onclick="location='http://www.website.com/' + myform.bike.options[myform.bike.selectedIndex].value + '/' + myform.model.options[myform.model.selectedIndex].value;"
```

Let me know if you need a worked solution.

You should also do a check to ensure that the user has selected something in the bike drop-down before allowing the button to be clicked. Otherwise the URL will not be valid.

Edit: here's a JSFiddle showing the complete solution: http://jsfiddle.net/V8jPn/1/